# Why this python script is sorting the divider of zero as one rather than zero?

Tags: python

I am really confused why this code is sorting the divider of zero as one! This is my code, by the way I am a beginner, so please be easy on me.

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    divisors = [1]
    for i in range(2, n):
        if (n % i)==0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return sum(divisors)
print(sum_divisors(0))
```

Comment: What do you mean with "sorting" here?

Comment: i mean the result of the function, when for example if i put 12, i will have 16 as output or as result, and a zero has no dividors so why i got 1 instead of 0???

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for "Minimal reproducible example".  We need you to show your expected output, the actual output, a clear problem description, and your debugging attempts.  Sticking in one or two simple `print` commands to trace your logic will show you what your code is doing.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided `divisors = [1]`. When you pass 0 as argument, your `for` loop becomes

`for i in range(2,0)`.

This basically means your `for` loop won't run at all. So, the default output for `sum(divisors)` will be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

First, formatting helps when you need an answer ;)

```py
def sum_divisors(n): 
  divisors = [1] # Note that you initialize the list to be [1]
  for i in range(2, n): 
    if (n % i)==0: 
      divisors.append(i) 
      return sum(divisors) 

print(sum_divisors(0))
```

Your initial list is set to be `[1]`. Add a check at the start that returns 0 if n < 1.

Comment: thank you veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery much Asher, i tried to add a checker but it was in the wrong place hhhh now i got the point, i tried it at the start and its running :-)  thank you bro, it means a lot for me!